# PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted while using Pyto on iPadOS 14

Tags: python, ios, pythonista

Please help :)

I just want to load a csv file so I wrote:

```
import os.path
print(os.path.abspath("example.csv"))
```

in the pythonista, I got the file path without error
however, in the pyto, it returned with
`PermissionError [Errno1] Operation not permitted`

The file is located on my laptop where I've already connected via smb address

Comment: FYI:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Library/LiveFiles/com.apple.filesystems.smbclientd/ZlgbEwTraining/Python/testscript.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(os.path.abspath("example1.txt"))
  File "Library/python38/posixpath.py", line 379, in abspath
    cwd = os.getcwd()
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
>>>

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. It turns out that Pyto need to confirm the scripts directory before exciting it.

I pressed the Settings icon at bottom, and pressed “Current Directory” to select the directory where the script located. After these steps I was able to run the codes above without errors.

Thank you!